# radio button has problem in selection problem in python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, radio-button

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x400+400+250")
window.title('Expenses Tracker')


class ExpensesTrack:
    row_list = []
    dict = dict()

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.title1 = Label(window, padx=15, pady=8, text='Enter the item').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.title_price = Label(window, padx=8, pady=8, text='Enter the price').grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.entry1 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN').grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN').grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.blank1 = Label(window).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)
        
        self.title3 = Label(window, text='Name of Item').grid(row=4, column=1 )
        self.title4 = Label(window, text='Price').grid(row=4, column=2)
       
        self.button1 = Button(window, text='Add', command=self.buttonclick).grid(row=1, column=4, padx=20)
        self.button2 = Button(window, text='Remove').grid(row=5, column=4, padx=15)


    def buttonclick(self):
        item = self.entry1.get()
        price = self.entry2.get()
        row = len(self.row_list) + 5

        self.namelabel = Label(window, text=item).grid(row=row, column=1)
        self.pricelabel = Label(window, text='$' + price).grid(row=row, column=2)
        self.entry1.delete(0, END)
        self.entry2.delete(0, END)
        self.radiobutton()
```

''' I have problem with last function. When click the button, radio button is appearing however, when I select second one, it keep adding more button. Last one is not unselecting. '''

```
    def radiobutton(self):
        row2 = len(self.row_list)
        self.var = IntVar()

        def select():
            int(self.var.get())

        button_radio = Radiobutton(window, variable= self.var, value=row2 + 5, command= select)
        button_radio.grid(row=len(self.row_list) + 5, column=0)
        self.row_list.append(self.row2)


e = ExpensesTrack(window)

window.mainloop()
```

''' my though on it that How can make a new object for button_radio. so I don't have rely on same object when press radio button. I have tried for loop to create new object. However, it loop through the list every time and it produce nested loop because, it will loop through again when i clicked the ADD button.'''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q8vB.png)

''' please share some thought on selection radio button as well thank you.'''

Comment: You have created new `IntVar` for newly added radiobutton.  Use single `IntVar` for all radiobuttons.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible because your code is not functional and it's easy to understand why. You can't write: `self.entry1 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN').grid(row=0, column=1)` because `grid` method doesn't return anything. You have to split your code:  `self.entry1 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN')` and `self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment  @Corralien. it is working you can try it.  you can type either self. 'entry1 = Entry(window, font=`NEWTIMESROMAN') and self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)' or either ` 
        self.entry1 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN').grid(row=0, column=1)`. I was using your code before. But, it was so long that I modified for stake overflow.

Comment: When I click on `Add` button, I have `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` for the reason I gave above.

Comment: @Corralien, thank you for kind comment. I have edited my code for stack overflow to simplified the body. it can fix  by adding new line for it. Sorry about it.

Comment: @acw1668, thank for solution. Now i have some insight. i would try to work on it.